# javascript - calculate and transform object key values into percentages (on 100%)

Tags: javascript, object, percentage

I have this object:

```
myObj = {
    red: "332",
    green: "632",
    yellow: "14",
    brown: "45",
    pink: "83",
    violet: "21",
    gray: "100",
    black: "33",
    white: "200"
};
```

I need to calculate and transform these object key values into percentages (on 100%)

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: So what is the transformation you wish to apply? "332 as a percentage" doesn't make sense on its own.

Comment: @RobG in this case 332 will have the highest percentage, 14 the lowest...

Comment: Why 332 and not 632? I think I'm stupid...

Comment: yes 632, I'm sorry.. you're right.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to get the percentage based off the highest number, here is an example with two loops (one to finding the max value and the other for changing actual values):

```js
var res = document.getElementById('r');
var myObj = {
    red: "332",
    green: "632",
    yellow: "14",
    brown: "45",
    pink: "83",
    violet: "21",
    gray: "100",
    black: "33",
    white: "200"
};

var max = 0;

for (var i in myObj) { // we find the max here
  if (parseInt(myObj[i], 10) > max) 
    max = myObj[i]; 
}

for (var i in myObj) { // we do the conversion here
  myObj[i] = (myObj[i] / max * 100) + "%";
  res.innerHTML += "<br>" + i + ": " + myObj[i]; // html output
}
```

```html
<div id="r"></div>
```

---

And if you wish to get the percentages of total (total being the sum of all values):

```js
var res = document.getElementById('r');
var myObj = {
    red: "332",
    green: "632",
    yellow: "14",
    brown: "45",
    pink: "83",
    violet: "21",
    gray: "100",
    black: "33",
    white: "200"
};

var total = 0;

for (var i in myObj) { // we find the total here
    total += parseInt(myObj[i], 10); 
}

for (var i in myObj) { // we do the conversion here
  myObj[i] = (myObj[i] / total * 100) + "%";
  res.innerHTML += "<br>" + i + ": " + myObj[i]; // html output
}
```

```html
<div id="r"></div>
```

Note: you might want to round those numbers off to a fewer number of decimals.

Comment: I don't mean that the higest value (green) will reach the 100%

Comment: Didn't you say 632 is the base (aka "percentage of what")?

Comment: the sum of the calculated percentages must be 100

Comment: Ah, okay, here is the update. It's actually almost identical, but instead of the max number, you're looking for the sum.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find the largest number. Then, you'll need to use that to find the percentages. So, say that you find that 632 is the largest number. Each other number's percentage will be that number divided by 632.